# How to get a number from a hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, cryptography

I'm trying to create random number between `0` and `1000000`(1 million) in `node.js`. Hash is:

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', "value").update("another value").digest('hex');
//d89c8a02a8b4e2461eeddcc3d8e85f2dfdab62968a329840ec5df2c0be2852eb9321cb35ff8fd5f43e97857a618d35edf9ba7fff56319c56eae4f8509f02e7eb
```

Random number

```
var number = parseInt(hash.substring(0, 5), 16); // 887240
```

But sometimes I'm getting numbers bigger than 1 million, how can I prevent this?

Comment: why are you using createHmac()? there's better tools, and this is not what createHmac() is for. try crypto.randomBytes()

Comment: Can you point me to other tools? I'm using a hash function because I need to prove this number is not manipulated by me or someone.

Comment: if you want a hash, use a hash, like md5 or something better, but i don't get where the random part comes in...

Comment: and why hash function would prove that number is not manipulated? its just always a hash of value. nothing more.

Comment: Yes I'm OK @owlstead

Comment: Thanks, this one is flawless.

Comment: I'll roll back your question to the one without the solution in a day or so. Please put the solution in an answer, per SO rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will put my answer when I am not in mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDRBG defines a simple (non FIPS compliant) DRBG that is basically just the NIST HMAC_Generate function this uses a chain of HMAC values. Please note that requesting 1 byte, followed by another one is not the same as asking 2 bytes at the same time.

---

The RandomInt class is the class that can use either the `randomBytes` from that class or from the `crypto` module of Node.js. It creates any random bounded number or a number in a range.

The `boundedRandomNumber` function first calculates how much bytes to ask for, which is a bit higher than the amount of bytes required. These bytes are then converted to a big integer, called `candidate`. Then this value is returned, modulus the bound.

The while loop makes sure that there is no skew towards the low end of the spectrum as the highest `candidate` values may return a value between 0 and X where X < bound after performing modulus `bound`. In that case more bytes are requested. With the current implementation, the chance that the loop is taken more than once is not very high though, so these functions should be relatively efficient.

---

So file `simpledrbg.js` should contain:

```
crypto = require('crypto');

exports.SimpleDRBG = function (k) {
    this.k = k;
    this.v = new Buffer(0);
}

exports.SimpleDRBG.prototype.randomBytes = function(bytes) {

    var result = new Buffer(0);
    var generatedBytes = 0;
    while (generatedBytes < bytes) {
        this.hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', this.k);
        this.hmac.update(this.v);
        this.v = this.hmac.digest();
        var tocopy = Math.min(this.v.length, bytes - generatedBytes);
        if (tocopy == this.v.length) {
            result = Buffer.concat([result, this.v]);
        } else {
            var vslice = this.v.slice(0, tocopy);
            result = Buffer.concat([result, vslice]);
        }
        generatedBytes += tocopy;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and `randomint.js` should contain:

```
crypto = require('crypto'),
bigint = require('bigint');
drbg = require('./simpledrbg');

function RandomInt(randomizer) {
    this.randomizer = randomizer;
}

/**
 * Returns a bounded random number, i.e. in the range [0..bound).
 * The highest possible value that may be returned is bound - 1.
 * Use boundedRandomNumber (bound + 1) if you want the bound value to
 * be the highest possible value that can be returned.
 */
RandomInt.prototype.boundedRandomNumber = function (bound) {
    BYTE_SIZE = 8;

    bigBound = bigint(bound);
    bigBoundLen = bigint(bigBound.bitLength());

    // request a higher number of bytes just to be sure that
    // the candidates are selected with high probability

    bytesToRequest = bigBoundLen.add(BYTE_SIZE).sub(1).div(BYTE_SIZE).add(1);

    // bigBound won't fit an integral number of times in the max value returned
    // so if it is higher than the largest n times bigBound, we need to try
    // again
    maxCandidateExcl = bigint(0x100).pow(bytesToRequest).div(bigBound).mul(bigBound);

    // just an assignment that will skip the initial test
    candidate = maxCandidateExcl;
    while (candidate.ge(maxCandidateExcl)) {
        bytes = this.randomizer.randomBytes(bytesToRequest.toNumber());
        candidate = bigint.fromBuffer(bytes);
    }

    // return the well distributed candidate % bound
    return candidate.mod(bigBound).toNumber();
}

/**
 * Returns a ranged random number, i.e. in the range [lowerBound..upperBound).
 * The highest possible value that may be returned is upperBound - 1.
 * Use rangedRandomNumber (lowerBound, upperBound + 1) if you want the upperBound value to
 * be the highest possible value that can be returned.
 */
RandomInt.prototype.rangedRandomNumber = function (lowerBound, upperBound) {
    return lowerBound + boundedRandomNumber (upperBound - lowerBound);
}

var randomIntTRNG = new RandomInt(crypto);
var testTRNG = randomIntTRNG.boundedRandomNumber(1000000);
console.log(testTRNG);

var randomIntDRNG = new RandomInt(new drbg.SimpleDRBG('seed'));
var testDRNG = randomIntDRNG.boundedRandomNumber(1000000);
console.log(testDRNG);
```

Comment: A very interesting module/class/object/function system JavaScript has. Then again, being able to either pass an `SimpleDRBG` instance or the entire module `crypto` is kind of cool.

Comment: Fixed final tests in my answer, I probably should have used the `var` keyword there.

Comment: I'm guessing that if you want a floating number, it would be a good idea simply to choose a specific precision and then divide by the right amount...

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you wish using hash for your problem you can: аccording to Wikipedia "...A randomness extractor, such as a cryptographic hash function, can be used to approach a uniform distribution of bits from a non-uniformly random source, though at a lower bit rate."

Take first sequential five hex digits [Log2(10^6) + 1] from good crypto hash function output (SHA512 is your choice). Test whether it less then or equal your upper bound.
Else test next 5 hex digits. The output will also has a uniform distribution.
Probability that 20 bit random number will be greater of your upper bound is p = 48575/1048576 = 0.0463247
If you split 128 digits on 25 non-overlapped subsets then probability that all subsets are bad is p^25 = 4.41*10^-34. If this is not negligible then calculate next hash. I took non-overlapped subsets for easiest probability calculation (for subset independency) but for your task you can shift by 1 hex digit and test up to 124 subsets.